# Creating a function in R, then regressing y on x

Tags: r, statistics

I need to create a function in R defined as: y = a + bx +e. Values have been given as: a = 1, b = 2, and e is a random draw from a normal distribution (mean = 0, sd = 1). Based on this, I create a function using the function command:
`function(a, bx, e)`

and create 'a', 'b', and 'e' as variables:

```
a <- 1

b <- 2

e <- rnorm(1, 0, 1)
```

I want to run the program so that it creates this function, but whenever I do, I get an error that it cannot find object 'x'. As I have these issues, I am unable to then run a regression of y on x.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple worked-through example from data generation to fitting a simple linear model.

```
# Set fixed RNG seed for reproducibility
set.seed(2017);

# Function to generate data
createData <- function(a = 1, b = 2, nPoints = 1000) {
    x <- runif(nPoints);
    y <- a + b * x + rnorm(nPoints, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    return(data.frame(x = x, y = y));
}

# Create sample data
df <- createData();
head(df);
#x         y
#1 0.9242426 3.7139739
#2 0.5371764 0.6020863
#3 0.4691956 2.0385870
#4 0.2886262 1.1376357
#5 0.7700882 2.0526688
#6 0.7727687 3.9418345

# Linear model
fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = df);
summary(fit);
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df)
#
#Residuals:
#    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
#-2.9886 -0.6923 -0.0166  0.7030  3.2497
#
#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept)  1.07750    0.06272   17.18   <2e-16 ***
#x            1.92354    0.11016   17.46   <2e-16 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 0.998 on 998 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.234,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2332
#F-statistic: 304.9 on 1 and 998 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

par(mfrow = c(2, 2));
plot(fit);
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I am trying to create a histogram of the result, but I am unsure of how to use the hist() command for this - which object should I use?

Comment: @Soppers I assume you'd like to show the distribution of the residuals in a histogram, in which case you can do e.g. `hist(fit$residuals, breaks = 30)`.